"Interview-Question" tag
it occurred to me the other day that we get quite a lot of questions on QSE about "interview questions", some of them quite interesting.
That is why I decided to introduce the "interview-question" tag and tried to tag a few such posts to "get the tag going": hopefully the community feel it's a useful tag?
The idea is that if we build up quite a few posts tagged as "interview-question" (say 100s), then I was hoping it would generate increased traffic to QSE as it will be easy for it to serve as a valuable resource for interview prep (whilst also making the website more popular).
The question is, do we think such initiative will attract the right attention and audience to QSE?
